# Creating an html document which can be manipulated with the jquery node.js module

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a string of html from a `$.ajax()` request (using the [jquery node.js package](https://npmjs.org/package/jquery)) that I want to scrape data from. From the documentation in the readme it would seem that `var $ = require('jquery');` creates a empty html document. Is it possible to replace that DOM with the html string so you can interact with it with jQuery like you would a typical website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$.get(URL, function(html) {
  var $doc = $(html);
  $doc.find('a').each(function(i, el) {
    console.log('href', $(el).attr('href'));
  });
});
```